# "Read Error" on boot

Tags: boot, hard-drive

So my computer froze while it was in powersave mode, and I could not reboot it with REISUB, or access it over the network, forcing me to hard reboot. When I rebooted, I was greeted with the message "Read Error" in the top left corner.

I booted into a LiveCD, and tried

```
fdisk -l
```

which gave me the following output:

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# fdisk -l
fdisk: unable to read /dev/sda: Inappropriate ioctl for device
```

I immediately imaged the drive with gddrescue, and then proceeded to run e2fsck. That seemed to complete successfully, and now when I run fsck, I get:

```
fsck from util-linux 2.20.1e2fsck 1.42.8 (20-Jun-2013)
/dev/sda1: clean, 1475560/18317312 files, 48594157/73242187 blocks
```

So all seems good over there. However, I still cannot get any output from fdisk, and when I reboot, I still get the same error.

Comment: what did your `gparted partition editor` shows?

Comment: It showed an ext4 partition at sda1 and an extended partition at sda1 which when expanded, opens up to show a swap partition at ext5

Comment: But I'm running from a LiveCD, so how will updating the kernel help?

Comment: Can you mount /dev/sda1 form the LiveCD? Could it be a corrupted MBR?

Comment: Yes, I was able to mount /dev/sda1. The end of the day, I just reformatted and reinstalled Ubuntu, and now all is fine. Just wish somebody would tell me why fdisk -l didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, What resolved the issue for me was using the live CD i installed Boot Repair,that repaired my file system which was mounted on partition sd1. After rebooting the initial boot took a bit more time than usual  but the machine worked fine after that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It's my first time installing Ubuntu and had the same "Read error" and **I solved it** in an almost **silly way**.

**MY PROBLEM**

I had disassembled my sister's netbook to make a back up of the hard drive before installing Ubuntu. Her netbook was running so slow on Windows that so I had to disassamble to have access to the drive. Then I installed Ubuntu (the Lubuntu distribution) easily but when I reebooted I had this **read error**.
So I simply suspected that when I re-assambled the netbook, I did not plug well the hard drive (excuse my poor english, I mean I didn't connect it correctly).

**MY SOLUTION**

So ***I simply disassambled the netbook*** again and connected strongly the hard drive.
When I rebooted, the Lubuntu worked normally.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same issue which displayed "read error" on the left corner of the screen
The solution is simple just open the case and unplug your HDD from motherboard and change the socket or cable, it may be damaged
Once it's done power on your computer and it'll work properly.
Good luck